# Modificar el titulo de la sección dinamicamente VueJs

Tags: vue.js

Tengo un front con VueJs y como template estoy utilizando inspinia.

```
           {{--SECTION TITLE--}}
            <div class="row wrapper border-bottom white-bg page-heading">
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <h2>Title</h2>

                    <ol class="breadcrumb">
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                            <a>Extra Pages</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">
                            <strong>Profile</strong>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>

            {{--MAIN CONTENT--}}
            <div class="wrapper wrapper-content">
                <router-view ></router-view>
            </div>
```

El código anterior esta divido en dos, el contenido principal que se muestra en el router view y la parte de arriba que tiene:

> `<h2> Title </h2>`

```
<ol>
  <li>
     home / section / sub-section
```

No estoy sabiendo la manera correcta de que el titulo cambie dinamicamente, es decir, si yo accedo a Home, que el titulo de la sección cambie a home, si entro a usuarios que muestre Usuarios y así.

Pensaba en un componente donde se inserte en cada una de las views y por props modificar el título o mixins pero no estoy seguro que sea lo mas óptimo.

Estoy aprendiendo Vuex y no sabría si con esto tambíen se podría resolver el problema!

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre crear un watcher en el componente template:

```
watch: {
  '$route' (to, from) {
    // code aquí
  }
}
```

Luego, simplemente extraer el pathname de la instancia de `$route` que mapea al `from` o simplemente usar el objeto `window`:

```
this.title = from.path.split('/').pop()
```

Por último, agrega una propiedad `title` y úsala en tu template:

```
data: () => ({
  ...
  title: 'Default title'
})
```

Comment: Lo probare y te digo que tal fue, graciaS!